# How to allocate_ids correctly?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7, webapp2

I want my ids to be < 999999999 but now trying to program that it seems to have the opposite effect, I'm only getting ids larger and when I try to allocate ids start > end ?

```
start, end = User.allocate_ids(max=999999999)
logging.info('start %d' % start)
logging.info('end %d' % end)
lower = start if start < end else end
key = User(id=lower).put()
logging.info('key: '+str(key))
user = key.get()
user.add_auth_id(email)
```

My log output show that the ID that gets allocated is wrong:

```
2012-02-13 03:19:07.396 start 98765439124
I 2012-02-13 03:19:07.396 end 98765439123
```

How can I fix this?

### Update

The dirty workaround I end up using is making sort of an own ID system which I should not do but it was the only solution in this case and I do not think this will create conflicts or duplicates, it just might be slow if entities start filling up, but for now this seems like a solution that works acceptably towards the user though it might not look that good looking at the code:

```
    new_id = random.randint(1,999999999)
    logging.info('testing new id: %d' % new_id)
    while User.get_by_id(new_id) != None:
        new_id = random.randint(1,999999999)
    logging.info('creating new id: %d' % new_id)
    key = User(id=new_id).put()
```

Comment: The numbers in your sample code and the text of your question don't match.

Comment: @proppy That's because I tried both 999999999 and 99999999 if that could make a difference but it didn't.

Comment: Why don't you just use the key_name instead of id? I don't think there is a point in trying to create your own id system, its not an easy task in a distributed environment.

Comment: All I need is to set a maximum for my IDs. I didn't invent the stupid ID system where there is a 9 number limit to the ID, I'm just the one who should program it. And I don't know how I could use key_name instead of ID since the number is exactly like an ID, it should work as the unique identifier for the user entity and my only constraint is that it should be at most 9 digits. Can't it be done? If you have an idea how this can be done with key_name instead of id, please post it.

Comment: For creating an entity with a key name, just pass a string as the id parameter: `User(id="my_hand_crafted_id")`.

Comment: @proppy thank you for the instruction. Now if I only knew how to create the ID, not just setting it. My IDs should be exactly like appengine IDs but with at most 9 digits so they should be somewhat sequential and between 0 and 999999999. Maybe I can just create an entity for each of these numbers and assign them a value if they're taken, but that solution will take so much more time to implement and everything else is done except just limiting appengine to making IDs < 1000000000

Comment: You don't have to create it, use pass any string as the id parameter and it will be used at the key name.

Comment: @proppy but I still must keep the ID unique and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: just enforce in your code that the id you compose is always unique, also make sure that you are passing the id as a string in the Model constructor.

Comment: @proppy thanks for all the info. I pass the id as an int so that it becomes the number key and I've updated the question how I assign new IDs. I hope the way I found is not terribly awful but it can assign a new ID that will not conflict by randomizing until a fitting key is found.

Comment: @nick if you pass the id as an int it can conflict with preallocated id, why don't you just use a string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained in [NDB documentation](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/document/d/1dsx1hihmMXMJm8wIRu49tJR-KEng80o3wkg4Nlbqn-w/edit#heading=h.n6bciud18zbk): `allocateIds(max=)` will returns the first id that is available, in case you try to reserve IDs that have already been allocated.

In your case all ids up to `999999999` already have been allocated before (maybe by other calls to `allocate_ids`), 98765439124 is the first id that is available, 98765439123 is the last one that have been allocated.

See the following example:

```
>>> Foo.allocate_ids(max=26740080011040)
(26740080011031L, 26740080011040L)
```

*Allocate all ids up to 26740080011040*

```
>>> Foo.allocate_ids(max=26740080011040)
(26740080011041L, 26740080011040L)
```

*All ids up to 26740080011040 already have been allocated, first available ids is 26740080011041, last allocated is 26740080011040*

```
>>> Foo.allocate_ids(max=26740080011050)
(26740080011041L, 26740080011050L)
```

*Allocate all ids up to 26740080011050*

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still can't create IDs according to my spec. My ID should be something like 460000005005 where I could treat this ID as 5005 since 46 is a dummy for the country code. I didn't invent that ID system, I'm just the one who should program it. It is naturally limited to IDs of size 999999999 so finding out that I can't allocate lower IDs really just puts the nails in my coffin and doesn't solve anything. Shouldn't it be possible to ask the datastore for a low ID a repeating number of times? It seems I can only do it once, then it allocates all IDs.

Comment: If you are looking for hand crafted id, you should definitely use `key_name` as suggested Shay Erlichmen in the comment.

Comment: It's exactly like appengine ID but begins with 460 and has at most 9 digits. So I created a filter called makeid that just displays my ID from the appengine ID and my whole app is built that way. Now it seems I allocated all the IDs that could be used and there's no way to deallocate them. I would like a simple solution but I don't know how to create unique numbers with Key_name since my IDs also should be unique numbers and more like sequential but not necessarily - what's important is just that the numbers have at most 9 digits.

Comment: See my comment on your question.

Comment: I think it's working acceptable now. To fulfil my strange requirement (IDs must be less than 10000000) I generate a new random number in that range, check to see if it is taken and if not which usually is the case, it creates the new user object with that ID as its numeric ID. It appears to work even though I got recommendations to use `key_string` instead of numeric key but I also need to use this ID to uniquely identify a user ina list of many users.